# VS 2022: "Unresolved external" error when calling methods that are defined outside of the class definition

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker-errors, unresolved-external

So, I've tried to run the simplest C++ program imaginable in Visual Studio 2022:

main.cpp:

```
#include "TestClass.h"

int main() {
    TestClass().testMethod();
}
```

TestClass.h:

```
#pragma once
class TestClass {
public:
    void testMethod();
};
```

TestClass.cpp:

```
#include "TestClass.h"

inline void TestClass::testMethod() {

}
```

But for some reason, I get nothing but a linker error:

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl TestClass::testMethod(void)" (?testMethod@TestClass@@QEAAXXZ) referenced in function main
```

I know that there are tons of questions on Stack Overflow discussing that specific error, but I wasn't able to find anything that applied to my situation, except for [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35963152/c-calling-static-method-in-another-class-causes-unresolved-external-symbol), which doesn't have an answer.

All files are included in the project (everything was generated in Visual Studio), I do not get any warnings from IntelliSense, and every file on its own compiles just fine (using Ctrl+F7)

I have no clue what is going on and would appreciate any help.

Comment: `inline void TestClass::testMethod() {` your bug is `inline` remove it and leave the rest.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: @drescherjm Removing `inline` doesn't change anything, besides, this is generated by VS2022 when "Move function definition" is executed

Comment: @KenWhite Thanks, but if one of the 37 answers has the solution that I need, I'm not capable of understanding and applying it correctly.

Comment: I just tried it with VS2022. The `inline` is the culprit for sure. Also, the `inline` generated by VS2022 is incorrect. [Apparently](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43245545/3740047), the function is meant for moving code to the header.

Comment: After restarting Visual Studio, everything worked without the `inline`. Thank you all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ `inline` functions must have their body present in every translation unit from which they are called.

> Removing inline doesn't change anything

Try to test it. I'm not the only one who proves that `inline` causes the lnk error. As
Sedenion says, it's a usage error.

I recommend reporting this wrong behavior to [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/search?space=62) and posting the link in this thread.

Comment: There already is a request to fix it: [https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Move-Definition-Location-should-not-add/1015726](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Move-Definition-Location-should-not-add/1015726)